# Get Facebook Page review - reviewer field is empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I pull page reviews with graph api.
But the reviewer field is empty.
The page access token has this permissions:
[image]

My facebook app doesn't have any permission or review.

What is the problem?

Best regards,
Feco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soultion is that the app need pages_read_engagement permission.
Not the standard access, but the advanced access.
To get this have to to send app to review.